# Why does a boolean function return false even after successfully executing it?

Tags: function, excel, boolean, vba

I have a boolean function "Test" in Module1, for example:

```
Function Test() As Boolean
MsgBox "Testing"
End Function
```

Now even after successfully executing it, I receive a False. Why is that?

```
If Module1.Test = True Then
MsgBox "True"
ElseIf Module1.Test = False Then
MsgBox "False"
End If
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `False` is the default return value if you don't explicitly specify something else, it will always return `False`.

To change that, you need to place these statements where appropriate within the function:

```
Test = False

Test = True
```

Comment: i was looking for confirmation that false is indeed the default return value. i found it in this answer even though i dont even understand the question. ;-)